# Error ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sentinel2, sentinelsat

I am working on importing Sentinel 2 satellite images to jupyter notebook for applying raster analysis but while importing I have faced this issue:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI
user = 'Username' 
password = 'password' 
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home')

from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon

footprint = None
for i in nReserve['geometry']:
    footprint = i

import time
#time.sleep(3)
products = api.query(footprint,
                 date = ('20190601','20190610'),
                 platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                 processinglevel = 'Level-2A',
                 cloudcoverpercentage = (0,10)
                )
```

The query string is too long and will likely cause a bad DHuS response.
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think that this message:

> The query string is too long and will likely cause a bad DHuS response

means that there is something wrong with your query.
Check the **footprint** as all other parameters in query seems ok.

Comment: Thanks, Ioannis for your response, But the same result without any change.